# Connect to Mongo Atlas Secondary

Tags: mongodb-atlas

On Cloud Mongo (Mongo Atlas) Free tier, it has 3 members of servers. How can I connect to the **Secondary** host from Mongo shell? Their example only shows how to connect to **Primary**.

```
"members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "***-shard-00-00-***.mongodb.net:27017",
            ....
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "***-shard-00-01-***.mongodb.net:27017",
            .....
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "***-shard-00-02-***.mongodb.net:27017",
            .....
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `--ssl` flag and specify `authSource`.

Try:

```
mongo "mongodb://***-shard-00-02-***.mongodb.net:27017/?authSource=admin" --ssl
```

at the very minimum. Of course you can add options for username, password, database to connect, etc...

```
mongo "mongodb://<username>:<password>@***-shard-00-02-***.mongodb.net:27017/<database>?authSource=admin" --ssl
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to connect to secondary through `mongosh`

Here are the steps:

- Retrieve the hostname from the Atlas cluster by clicking **View Monitoring** on the cluster
- Copy the secondary node hostname without the port number. For example: `clustername-shard-00-01.abcde.mongodb.net`
- To connect to the node, run the following `mongosh` command from the command line, replacing `<secondary hostname>` with the secondary hostname you copied in the previous step, and replacing `<database user>` with the database user created for the project:

`mongosh "mongodb://<secondary hostname>/myFirstDatabase" --tls --authenticationDatabase admin --username <database user>`